# Отображение информации посередине

Tags: html

Как вот эту часть

```
<div style='width:100px;border:1px solid black;'>
  <div align="left" style='center:0px;width:<?php round( 100 * $life / $all_life ); ?>%;background-color:green;' HSPACE=100 VSPACE=0><?php  echo "{$row['all_life']}"; echo "/{$row['life']}"; } ?></div>
```

поставить в средину. Каким макаром я только не пробовал, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div style='width:100px;border:1px solid black; margin-left: 46%;'>
```

Comment: Правильно спасибо =)